# Reuse margin top and bottom for different divs?

Tags: css

Hey guys I'm not sure how you guys handle this, but I assign a div to every label, chunk of text or image and then write a CSS class for margin or padding top and bottom to space things out nicely. Problem is, in my stylesheet now I find that half of divs in there do nothing but this.

```
.example-div {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.second-example-div {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Do you declare a few of these classes and reuse them or do you make them all unique even though the code is repeated?

I was thinking of doing something like this and reusing them since nearly all my divs use margins. Is this a bad idea?

```
.margin-small {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.margin-large {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

I'm also using Bootstrap but I don't think there's something like this built in. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a css class to apply those styles is the best way, and you can re-use it as-needed on the divs you want to style that way. You should definitely not be rewriting the same css for every div in a new class. There's no need to make classes unique, they're designed to be reusued. Div IDs are for uniqueness, classes are for re-use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS pre-processors like LESS or SASS, where you could find lot of features like mixins.